# How can I change text colour in sublime text?

Tags: text, colors, ide

I want to color source code as i want. For example, if I have this code

```
<script>
var x = 1;
function yu() {
           document.getElementById("e").innerHTML = "O";
}
</script>
```

I want to color the whole function ( lines 3,4,5), or color just a line or a word. I don't want sublime text to color every word depending of the type of the words.

If it cant be done in sublime text, do  you know other source code editros or IDE which an do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom `syntax` which meets your criteria and set it as the default syntax for any filetypes you wish to affect.

---

Here is a basic syntax example which affects files with the extension `.MyExtension`

[image: Example]

Save the following code @:
`Packages/MySyntaxFiles/MyCustomSyntax.sublime-syntax`

```
%YAML 1.2

---

name: MyCustomSyntax
file_extensions: [ MyExtension ]
scope: source.MyScopeName

contexts:

  main:
    - match: '\bfunction.*?{'
      push: function
    - match: '\b<.+?>\b'
      scope: entity.name.tag

  function:
    - meta_scope: entity.name.function
    - include: braces

  braces:
    - match: '{'
      push: braces
    - match: '}'
      pop: true
```

**Note:** *This example meets the minimal requirements of the code sample you provided. You will likely need to elaborate upon this template in order for it to fully meet your actual usage requirements.*

---

### Resources:

[**SublimeText > Official Documentation > Syntax**](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html)

[**SublimeText > Unofficial Documentation > Syntax Definitions**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html)

[**ScopeHunter**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter)
*Use this to find scopes that you might want to replicate*

[**PackageResourceViewer**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer)
*Use this to open existing* `sublime-syntax` *files for reference*

[**Color Schemes**](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/labels/color%20scheme)
*Browse the included* `tmTheme` *files to view commonly used scopes.

For maximum customization: create your own* `tmTheme` *file to match your syntax & scopes.*

[**RegExr**](http://www.regexr.com/)
*You will need a basic knowledge of* `RegEx` *in order to define scope matches.

RegExr has an excellent* `Reference` *section which covers most of the basics, along with a testing area so you can try things out as you learn.*

Comment: Thanks @KeithHall for the bracket matching improvement : )